# Replacing a part of a string with another

Tags: java, string

I am making a program that solves an equation.

I have a variable that changes: `i`, and a string that is entered: `parseLine`

What is the easiest way to make:

```
parseLine = "100 + x"
when i = 1;
```

into:

```
"100 + 1"
```

I tried

```
String ir = Double.toString(i);
parseLine.replace("x", ir);
```

but the output is still `100 + x`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

a `String` in java is *immutable* - you can't change it. The `replace` method returns a *new* `String` instance:

```
parseLine =  parseLine.replace("x", ir);
```

Comment: This is actually the first time I understand what "immutable" means! Thanks. +1

Comment: The sad part is this was one of those "easy questions to answer that gets lots of upvotes" ... and I was already over the reputation cap for the day, lol.

Comment: @BrianRoach in the end, you've helped make the internet a better place!